# BeautifulSoup select_all does not work with data-testid attribute

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the current prices from the search result page of Booking.com such as:

https://www.booking.com/searchresults.ja.html?lang=ja&dest_id=6411914&dest_type=hotel&checkin=2022-12-22&checkout=2022-12-23&group_adults=4&no_rooms=1&group_children=0&sb_travel_purpose=leisure

As you can see, each property's information are stored in <div data-testid="property-card" ...>

[image]

So I tried with this code, which returns 0 result.

```
cards = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'data-testid': 'property-card'})
```

Trying to filter with CSS works okay off-course, but in this case I'd love to go with data-testid.
Does the code above work at your end? What do you think I am missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tag that you are looking for isn't in the soup object.

Here is the soup for the first hotel from your URL, which is *Cup of Tea Ensemble*

```
<div class="bui-carousel__item" data-bui-ref="carousel-item" data-lp-ga-click="hotel-group-3:click:4">
          <div class="hotel-card__default bui-card bui-card--media" data-et-click="customGoal:BPHMAbFJfYCSKBZBLSRe:5" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Hotel" onclick="location.href='/hotel/jp/cup-of-tea-ensemble.ja.html'">
           <div class="bui-card__image-container">
            <img alt="cup of tea ensemble、高山市のホテル" class="bui-card__image" itemprop="image" src="https://cf.bstatic.com/xdata/images/hotel/270x200/284494395.jpg?k=44610a2487cb129768a450003e9cd7582e8c04c8db251f005b80d533244e1a39&amp;o=">
            </img>
           </div>
           <div class="bui-card__content">
            <header class="bui-card__header bui-spacer--medium">
             <a class="bui-card__header_full_link_wrap" href="/hotel/jp/cup-of-tea-ensemble.ja.html" title="cup of tea ensemble">
              <h3 class="bui-card__title" itemprop="name">
               cup of tea ensemble
              </h3>
              <p class="bui-card__subtitle" itemprop="address" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
               <span itemprop="addressLocality">
                高山市（高山市）のホテル
               </span>
              </p>
             </a>
            </header>
            <div class="bui-spacer--medium">
             <span class="bui-badge bui-badge--outline">
              ロケーションが良い
             </span>
            </div>
            <div class="hotel-card__text bui-spacer--medium">
             <p class="bui-card__text hotel-card__text--wrapped">
              cup of tea ensembleは高山市の飛騨高山温泉にあり、高山駅まで1km以内、飛騨民俗村・飛騨の里まで2.5km、藤井美術民芸館まで徒歩6分です。3つ星のホテルで、共用ラウンジ、エアコン付きのお部屋（無料WiFi、専用バスルーム付）を提供しています。共用キッチンと荷物預かりを提供しています。 cup of tea ensembleのお部屋にはそれぞれベッドリネンとタオルが備わります。...
              <span class="hotel-card__text_review">
               Super nice design, very good location close to the city center with coffee shops, bakerys and market...
              </span>
             </p>
             <div class="hotel-card__read_more_container js-hotel-card__read_more_container">
              <span class="hotel-card__read_more_button js-hotel-card__read_more_button" role="button" tabindex="0">
               <span class="hotel-card__read_more bui-link bui-link--secondary">
                もっと見る
               </span>
               <span class="hotel-card__read_less bui-link bui-link--secondary">
                折りたたむ
               </span>
              </span>
             </div>
            </div>
            <div class="bui-card__text">
             <div class="hotel-card__price bui-spacer--small">
              1泊あたり￥14,500～
             </div>
             <span class="review-score-widget review-score-widget__very_good review-score-widget__text-only review-score-widget__inline">
              <span aria-label="スコアは8.5" class="review-score-badge">
               8.5
              </span>
              <span aria-label="評価はとても良い" class="review-score-widget__text">
               とても良い
              </span>
              <span aria-label="クチコミ全77件をもとにしています" class="review-score-widget__subtext">
               クチコミ77件
              </span>
             </span>
            </div>
           </div>
          </div>
         </div>
```

The hotels are under this tag `soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class', 'bui-carousel__item'})`

Comment: Hello, I really appreciate your answer! Your suggested code actually worked as I wanted, but I have no idea how to check each class name in the soup object. With Chrome dev tools, the classname "bui-carousel__item" and such are invisible. 
Do you think I should print the whole soup object to check the actual HTML before coding?

Comment: Yes, you need to check the soup object, because it might be different that what you see with the Chrome dev tools.  I printed the soup to my workspace and then searched it using `Sublime text`.

Comment: Wow, that's quite tough job.. But thank you for your wisdom :)
This might be a bit side-tracked, but when I print the whole soup object, the contents totally look different from what I see on Chrome, even the HTML values. For instance, I would like to check the first hotel "cup of tea ensemble" but in the soup object that does not come in first. Does this happen to you?

Comment: Yes, the first hotel in the soup is different than what you see on the page. The content on the URL are being generated by `javascript`, so that is why the soup is different.  You can scrape the contents of the site with either `BeautifulSoup` or `Selenium`.

Comment: Thanks for your kind support! Looks like that scraping from the dynamic website is much harder than I expected.. So in this case, I first need to make Selenium driver get the html response, then parse the html into BeautifulSoup object... am I right?

Comment: Maybe, but maybe not.  What elements do you need to scrape from the page?  Does order matter to you?  Do you have to walk pages?

Comment: If my answer helped you please accept it.  If it didn’t help you please provide me the details why it didn’t.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249955/discussion-between-pomme-and-life-is-complex).