# BeautifulSoup object looks totally different from what I see in Chrome

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am in my first attempt in scraping react-based dynamic website - Booking.com search result page. I want to collect the current price of specific hotels under the same conditions.
This site was easy to scrape data with simple CSS selector before, but now they changed how to code and every elements what I want is described with "data-testid" attribute and the series of unknown random numbers, as far as I see in Chrome dev tool. Now the code what I wrote before does not work and I need to rewrite.

[image]

Yesterday, I got a wisdom [from another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74591178/beautifulsoup-select-all-does-not-work-with-data-testid-attribute/74591313?noredirect=1#comment131666679_74591313) that in this case what I see in Chrome developer tool is different from the HTML contents as of Soup object. So I tried printing the whole soup object beforehand to check the actual CSS, then select elements using these CSS class. I also made sure to use selenium to capture js-illustrated date.

At first this looking good, however, the returned soup object was totally different from what I see. For instance, [the request URL](https://www.booking.com/searchresults.ja.html?lang=ja&dest_id=6411914&dest_type=hotel&checkin=2022-12-22&checkout=2022-12-23&group_adults=4&no_rooms=1&group_children=0&sb_travel_purpose=leisure) should return a hotel called "cup of tea ensemble" on the top of the list with the price for 4 adults for 1 night from 2022-12-22 as its specified in the url params, but when looking into the soup object, the hotel does not come in first and most of the parameters I added in the url are ignored.

Does this usually happen when trying to scrape React-based website? If so, how can I avoid this to collect data as what I see in web browser?

I am not sure if this help but I am attaching the current code what I use. Thank you for reading and I appreciate any advice!

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

booking_url = 'https://www.booking.com/searchresults.ja.html?lang=ja&ss=Takayama&dest_id=6411914&dest_type=hotel&checkin=2022-12-22&checkout=2022-12-23&group_adults=4&no_rooms=1&group_children=0&sb_travel_purpose=leisure'
#booking_url = 'https://www.google.co.jp/'

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='./chromedriver', chrome_options=options)
driver.get(booking_url)
html = driver.page_source.encode('utf-8')

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
print(soup)
```

Comment: Usiing driver.page_source will still return the original source before javascript runs. You will need to discard BeautifulSoup and use sleeniums functions to find elements https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_elements

Comment: @JayTurnr Sure, if you don't allow any time to load, that might be so, but `page_source` should return the html as it is in the automated browser at the time you access it. I [use bs4+selenium](https://pastebin.com/E3sCEr9r) for many of my scraping projects that have js loading, but don't require a lot of automated interaction.

Comment: @pomme For me, it seems to work if I don't add `options` (i.e., just calling `webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='./chromedriver')`). It won't be headless anymore, but if you don't mind the automated chrome window popping up, then give it a try. Otherwise, you might have to code filling out and submitting the search form since the headless browser seems to open https://www.booking.com/city/jp/takayama.ja.html rather than the full `booking_url`

Comment: @Driftr95 Thanks for your comment! I would love to go with headless because I am going to cron this program on GCP. And I never knew about the redirect...! I am quite new to selenium and feel nervous about manipulating form, but will give it a try anyways.

Comment: @JayTurnr Thanks for your comment! I never knew about selenium's original functions to manipulate elements. Looking at its APIs, they're missing function to select elements by specific attributes and such. So I think I still need BeautifulSoup.

Answer (score 1):

The below code is producing the exact output what the browser displayed

```
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


webdriver_service = Service("./chromedriver") #Your chromedriver path
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service)

driver.get('https://www.booking.com/searchresults.ja.html?label=gen173nr-1FCAQoggJCDWhvdGVsXzY0MTE5MTRIFVgEaFCIAQGYARW4ARfIAQzYAQHoAQH4AQOIAgGoAgO4AuiOk5wGwAIB0gIkZjkzMzFmMzQtZDk1My00OTNiLThlYmYtOGFhZWM5YTM2OTIx2AIF4AIB&aid=304142&lang=ja&dest_id=6411914&dest_type=hotel&checkin=2022-12-22&checkout=2022-12-23&group_adults=4&no_rooms=1&group_children=0&sb_travel_purpose=leisure&offset=0')
#driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(5)


soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"lxml")
for u in soup.select('div[data-testid="property-card"]'):
    title = u.select_one('div[class="fcab3ed991 a23c043802"]').get_text(strip=True)
    print(title)
    #price = u.select_one('span[class="fcab3ed991 bd73d13072"]').get_text(strip=True)
    #print(price)
```

**Output:**

```
cup of tea ensemble
FAV HOTEL TAKAYAMA
ワットホテル&スパ飛騨高山
飛騨高山温泉 高山グリーンホテル
岡田旅館  和楽亭
ザ・町家ホテル高山
旅館あすなろ
IORI STAY
風屋
Tabist 風雪
飛騨高山　本陣平野屋　花兆庵
Thanyaporn Hotel
旅館むら山
cup of tea
つゆくさ
旅館　一の松
龍リゾート＆スパ
飛騨高山の宿 本陣平野屋 別館
飛騨牛専門 旅館 清龍
Tomato Takayama Station
民宿 和屋
ビヨンドホテル 高山 セカンド
旅館 岐山
Utatei
ビヨンドホテル高山1s
```

Comment: Thanks @Fazlulu for your sample code. That worked at my end too, but I would love to use headless browser to cron this on GCP, but when I add headless option, the request url somehow got redirects to another URL, as pointed on the comments below. Do you know any way to select elements from the specified URL using headless browsers, or just to prevent redirection ??